# Some strings not showing up during the translation in prestashop

Tags: bootstrap-4, prestashop, translation, prestashop-1.6

I have a tlp file with cms page inside, part of the code:

```
<div class="row">

                                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
                                                                    <center><a href="http://luckygrow.com/32-na-kwitnienie-90.html" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="{$img_dir}lg/bloom-spectrum.png" ></a></center>
                                                                        <div>
                                                                            <div class="thumbnail index-products-feature">       
                                                                                <div class="thumbnail-content">
                                                                                    <center><h4>{l s='YYYY°'}  </h4></center>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>              
                                                    <div class="row">               
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                                                    <center>
                                                                        <div style="margin:10px;">
                                                                            {l s='XXXX'} 
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </center>   
                                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
```

The problem is that the string "YYYY" is showing up in the transaltion module, but the "XXXX" is not apearing

Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to flush your cache or something ? It actually should work. If you are inside a module, you need to keep simple quote and use module name in your function like this :

```
{l s='String to translate' mod='yourmodulename'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out !
You can not have an "enter" / new line inside your code, somehow presta does not recognize it as a string that might be be translated